# Dynamically generated buttons and pass variable to new window with JSON

Tags: json, titanium-mobile

First I am a beginner and this is my first app. I have been working on this app for several days and I am stuck. On the page remote_read-org-3.js I am creating buttons that are a list of states. These are being pulled from a mySQL database. This part is working. I need to pass the stateabbr to the next window when the button is clicked. The problem is it passes the last state in the list no matter which button I click.
This is remote_read-org.js It may not been the cleanest code but I am still working through the how to's

```
var currentWin = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

var view02 = Titanium.UI.createView({
         top:0,
        left:0,
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        backgroundImage: 'images/wcs_background_2.jpg',
})

var label01 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text: "US STATES",
    top:25,
    left:125,
    height:'auto',
    width:'175',
    textAlign: "left",
    font:{fontFamily:'Arial',fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:24},
    color: "#1c1e3b",
})

var label02 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text: "Attachments",
    top:50,
    left: 125,
    height:'24',
    width:'150',
    textAlign: "left",
    font:{fontFamily:'Arial',fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:18},
    color: "#1c1e3b",
})

var view01 = Titanium.UI.createView({
        top:90,
        left:70,
        height: 375,
        width: Ti.UI.FILL,
})

var currentWin = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

var sendit = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
sendit.open('GET', 'http://localhost/test/read.php');
sendit.send();
sendit.onload = function(){
    var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

    var json = json.states;

    var dataArray = [];

    var scroller =  Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    height: Ti.UI.FILL,
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,
});

    var brandView = Ti.UI.createView({   //Primary view for buttons
        title: 'Hello',
        top:0,
        left:0,
        height      : Ti.UI.FILL,
        width       : Ti.UI.FILL,
        contentHeight : "auto",
        backgroundColor : "transparent",
        layout      : "horizontal",
        horizontalBounce :false,
});

scroller.add(brandView);

view01.add(scroller);

    var pos;
    for( pos=0; pos < json.length; pos++){

        dataArray.push({title:'' + json[pos].stateAbbr + ''});
        // set the array to the tableView
        var btn = Ti.UI.createButton({
        title: json[pos].stateAbbr,
        width: 60,
        height: 70,
        top: pos * 0, // space the buttons at 105
        left: 2,
        backgroundImage: 'images/state_icon.png', 
        MyID: json[pos].stateAbbr,
    });

    btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) { 

        var newWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow({ 
            url: 'remote_read_acc.js', 
            MyID: btn.MyID
            }); 
newWindow.open(newWindow);

});

    brandView.add(btn);

    };

};

var brandView = Ti.UI.createView({
});

view02.add(view01);

view02.add(label01);
view02.add(label02);

currentWin.add(view02);
```

I need to pass the stateabbr to this new window
remote_read_acc.js

```
var currentWin = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

var view02 = Titanium.UI.createView({
         top:0,
        left:0,
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        backgroundImage: 'images/wcs_background_2.jpg',
})

var label01 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text: "US STATES",
    top:25,
    left:125,
    height:'auto',
    width:'175',
    textAlign: "left",
    font:{fontFamily:'Arial',fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:24},
    color: "#1c1e3b",
})

var label02 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text: "Attachments",
    top:50,
    left: 125,
    height:'24',
    width:'150',
    textAlign: "left",
    font:{fontFamily:'Arial',fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:18},
    color: "#1c1e3b",
})

var view01 = Titanium.UI.createView({
        top:90,
        left:90,
        height: 375,
        width: Ti.UI.FILL,
})

var currentWin = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

var sendit = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
sendit.open('GET', 'http://localhost/test/attachments.php');
sendit.send();
sendit.onload = function(){
    var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

    var json = json.attachments;

    var dataArray = [];

    var scroller =  Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    height: Ti.UI.FILL,
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,
});

    var brandView = Ti.UI.createView({   //Primary view for buttons
        title: 'Hello',
        top:0,
        left:0,
        height      : Ti.UI.FILL,
        width       : Ti.UI.FILL,
        contentHeight : "auto",
        backgroundColor : "transparent",
        layout      : "horizontal",
        horizontalBounce :false,
});

scroller.add(brandView);

view01.add(scroller);

    var pos;
    for( pos=0; pos < json.length; pos++){

        dataArray.push({title:'' + json[pos].attachmentName + ''});
        // set the array to the tableView
        var btn = Ti.UI.createButton({
        title: json[pos].attachmentName ,
        width: 190,
        height: 30,
        top: pos * 0, // space the buttons at 105
        left: 2,
        MyID: json[pos].attachmentName,
    });

    btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) { 

        var newWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow({ 
            url: '', 
            }); 
newWindow.open(newWindow);

    brandView.add(btn);

    };

};


var brandView = Ti.UI.createView({
});


view02.add(view01);

view02.add(label01);
view02.add(label02);

currentWin.add(view02);
```

I also then need to use that stateabbr that I passed to query the dataArray to pull just the values from the array that matches the stateabbr variable. so I can display them on this page.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It's passing the last state in the list cause you are adding event listeners in a for loop and ignoring JavaScript scope rules (they are not the easiest to understand that's for sure). So what is happening is that `btn` is always equal to the last `btn` you create.  Instead try this, use the `source` attribute of every `click` event, this separates your inner scope from the outer scope of the for loop:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) { 

    var newWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow({ 
        url: 'remote_read_acc.js', 
        MyID: e.source.MyID // Get the actual button that was clicked
    }); 
    newWindow.open(newWindow);
});
```

To optimize this even further I would move the event listener function outside of the loop. Also, I wouldn't use the `url` attribute of the window, as that will open an entirely different JavaScript context, which is pretty heavyweight, instead try to use the `require()` CommonJS directive.